# Google Maps API Get coordinates only in the first marker placement

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I´m creating a Map with the Google Maps API and the purpose of it is that you can only place 1 marker and then drag it around the map. I need to get the coordinates of the marker on each location, when it´s placed the first time and also every time is dragged.

I´ve been looking through lot of answers, and spent lots of hours with that, but really doesn´t solve this issue, here is my code:

```
<!-- Google Maps API -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadmap() {
    // initialize map
    var marker;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, -40),
        zoom: 1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        streetViewControl: false
    });
    // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
    map.addListener('click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
        document.getElementById('displayLat').value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById('displayLong').value = event.latLng.lng();
    }); 
    map.addListener(marker,'dragend', function(event) {
        document.getElementById('displayLat').value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById('displayLong').value = event.latLng.lng();
    }); 
    // Adds a marker to the map.
    function placeMarker(location) {
      if ( marker ) {
      }else{
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,                
            position: location,
            map: map
        });
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

The scripts works halfway only as I get the coordinates everytime I click the map (either if the marker is already placed) and I don´t get the coordinates when I drag the marker.

I´m newbie in Javascript, and from my understanding I have to place some kind of "if" condition inside the listener so if the marker is already placed to not give the coordinates of the "click" action, but I don´t know how to approach.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hello @etrull I have done simple project using Google Map using the tools may be this will solve your problem please look into this http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues with your code.  First, addressing your problem.  You've got

```
map.addListener(marker,'dragend', function(event) {
```

but that addListener function only takes 2 parameters, the event type and the callback function.  And you're adding this listener to the map, not the marker.  Change it to this:

```
marker.addListener('dragend', function(event) {
```

Secondly, you've got an event listener for when the user clicks the map, and every single time, you're checking if they've created the marker already or not, so you only ever end up creating it once.  That's fine, there's nothing wrong with your code.  However there's a much better way of doing it.

You can use the google.maps.event.addListenerOnce function, which only executes once.  So using that you can simplify your code slightly:

```
function loadmap() {
    var marker;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(20, -40),
        zoom: 1,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        streetViewControl: false
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,                
            position: event.latLng,
            map: map
        });

        marker.addListener('dragend', function(event) {
            document.getElementById('displayLat').value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById('displayLong').value = event.latLng.lng();
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

I'd also only want to add the marker's event listener after you've created the marker.